# Нарушился CSS у ссылок к ответам

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, ссылки

Нарушился CSS у ссылок к ответам:

> [image]

[Аналогичный вопрос на MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341868/underline-overflow-in-links-under-answers)

Comment: Непонятно, что именно не так. Подчёркивание что ли?

Comment: @Qwertiy У ссылок появился `text-decoration: underline;` и отдельный стиль для `:visited`

Comment: Был временный баг с CSS. Адам уже [поправил](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341881/260198).